# Cannot login to Agora RTM with Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui, agora.io

So I am attempting to implement Agora RTM within my SwiftUI app. Below is the code I am using to attempt to log on but I keep getting error code 3.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
class AgoraChatOO: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var chatMessages: [ChatMessage] = []
    @Published var kit: AgoraRtmKit?
    @Published var rtmChannel: AgoraRtmChannel?
    
    func updateKit(appId: String, delegate: AgoraRtmDelegate, channelDelegate: AgoraRtmChannelDelegate) {
            kit = AgoraRtmKit(appId: appId, delegate: delegate)

            guard let kit = kit else { return }
            
            print(kit)
            print(delegate)
            print(channelDelegate)
        
        kit.login(byToken: "my temp token", user: UIDevice.current.name) { [unowned self] (error) in
                if error != .ok {
                    print("Error logging in: ", error.rawValue)
                } else {
                    self.rtmChannel = kit.createChannel(withId: "testChannel", delegate: channelDelegate) //This is the AgoraRtmChannelDelegate, which must be set to get messageReceived, memberLeft, and memberJoined callbacks.
                    
                    self.rtmChannel?.join(completion: { (error) in
                        if error != .channelErrorOk {
                            print("Error joining channel: ", error.rawValue)
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        }
}
```

I have tried setting the token parameter to nil to test and have guaranteed a fresh one when I have tested with one as above.

Comment: I also tried calling the logout function after "kit" was instantiated to be sure I wasn't already actually logged in.  Calling the login function still produces error code 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok this one was rather easy after all. Only certain characters are allowed for the user parameter string, and a character limit is also enforced.  Changing to a more simple string corrected the issue (thanks Matt Frazer for you suggestion).

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to run the Demo Project:

1. Please change the uid to a simple string (eg:'123')
   2.try to run your project, if it shows the error code 5, then try to create a new project in agora as mentioned in this link:

https://github.com/AgoraIO/RTM/issues/58#issuecomment-609409392

do not forget to replace the agora app id with new app id.